# How to create access table from Spring security based application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-security

Recently, I join a team which is working on a server. There are many module and API and my task is to prepare Access Table document of REST APIs. For example, there is an API to get a list of contents:

```
GET: /api/v2/cms/contents
```

On the Other hand, many authorities in the modules:

- manager
- view
- anonymous
- ...

I have to know which authorities are required to call the REST?!

Good news is, there are many integration tests (implemented with JUnit and spring test).

I want to run tests and log access check as follow:

```
{TEST Name}: {list of required authorities}
```

Is there any way to mock security and integrates with JUnit to collect required authorities during a test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@WithMockUser` for mock Spring Security.

See the documentation for more detail.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html

Comment: Dear Gaurav, Is it possible to collect the required authorities during a test case?

Comment: @WithMockUser(username = "user1", password = "pwd", roles = "USER")